Cache different page versions based on country
I have a SvelteKit site implementing the Shopify Storefront API. To show different prices / currencies for different countries, I intialize and send a "country" cookie to the server on every request.
As I now want to cache these pages, it might occur that users only get the cached countries' version. Therefore, I would like to cache different versions of the page based on what country the user has selected.
I've looked into the Vary: Cookie header, but this would lead to caching different versions whenever any cookie value changes.
Is there another way to achieve this?

Some sites have the country as a path parameter, is that not an option?

would like to avoid this as the content really only differs in the value + currency, we don‘t have any other translated content

On a technical level it could still be the same route, if you object because of optics (the parameter not having an effect on language) that is understandable.

yes, the optics are the reason. i have also looked into using a custom header (e.g. X-Country) and use it in the Vary header, but then I‘d need to add this header to all requests which feels quite clunky. Thought about manipulating the request in a hooks.server.ts to get the cookie and transform it into the new header, but wouldn‘t this require a round trip to the server for each load und thus somehow „deny“ the caching functionality?

Agree that this probably is impractical/does not work.

Another option is not to have value and currency in the page, but only render them when the page is hydrated on the client. This information would be a spinner / skeleton / other place holder when rendered on the server-side. This way all pages get served the same HTTP content and the information is not filled until the client renders the page.

wouldn‘t this be disadvantageous for SEO as the information about the currency would be missing e.g. on the product page? For the product list, I‘d also imagine it harsh for crawlers because I‘d need to fetch all the products on the client-side to avoid having to request (and potentially map) the currency data on top
